# How to do Relationship ManytoMany with Java Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I would like to update my application, currently, I have users and a general category list and I would like to add a category list by the user except for admin users who have all categories.
So I was thinking about doing a ManyToMany relationship. I saw that it wasn't necessary to make a table only of IDs.

I am using Spring Boot with JPA and MongoDB as my database.

```java
\\Models
@Document(collection = "users")
public class AppUser {

    @Transient
    public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "users_sequence";

    @Id
    private int id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;

    @DBRef
    private  AppRole role = new AppRole();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
    private  List<AppCategory> lstCategory = new ArrayList();
}
@Document(collection = "categories")
public class AppCategory {

    @Transient
    public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "category_sequence";
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String libelle;
}
```

3nd table version

```
public class AppUser {
...
 @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
      name = "usersCategories", 
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user"), 
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Category"))
    private  List<AppCategory> lstCategorie = new ArrayList<AppCategory>();
...
}
@Document(collection = "usersCategories")
public class AppUserCategory {

@DBRef
private  AppUser User = new AppUser();
@DBRef
private  AppCategory Category = new AppCategory();

}
```

Comment: With a relational db you would have to use a 3rd table for the id-id mapping to support many-to-many. In Mongo you'd probably want to store arrays of ids in your documents but I'm not sure how exactly you'd map that since I didn't use the JPA/Mongo combo myself yet. However, note that `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")` would actually require a `tags` attribute in `AppCategory`.

Comment: See this post [Designing Many-to-Many relationships in MongoDB (instead of relational tables)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66152296/designing-many-to-many-relationships-in-mongodb-instead-of-relational-tables/66153810#66153810). See the MongoDB documentation for useful info: [Data Modeling Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/).

Comment: I read that there are 2 possibilities one with a 3rd table and another with only annotation .I add the 3rd table version but does not work. do you need the DOA and services ?

Answer (score 0):

```java
\\Models
@Document(collection = "users")
public class AppUser {

    @Transient
    public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "users_sequence";

    @Id
    private int id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;

    @DBRef
    private  AppRole role = new AppRole();

    @DBRef
    private  List<AppCategory> lstCategory = new ArrayList();
}
@Document(collection = "categories")
public class AppCategory {

    @Transient
    public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "category_sequence";
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String libelle;
}
```

```json
//exemple user
{
  "_id": 1,
  "username": "myusername",
  "email": "myusername@gmail.com",
  "password": "",
  "role": {
    "$ref": "role",
    "$id": 1
  },
  "lstCategory": [
    {
      "$ref": "categories",
      "$id": 2
    },
    {
      "$ref": "categories",
      "$id": 3
    }
```

just need @DBRef